# Can I provide several defaults for a template member function?

Tags: c++, templates

As a huge fan of C++, there have been a question in my mind. The question is:

The classic book "Modern C++ Design" says: "The library writer cannot provide multiple default values. At best, a class template implementer can provide a single default implementation for each member function. You cannot provide several defaults for a template member function." (see "1.4 The benefit of templates")

What does the author actually mean?

To my understanding, "several defaults" is a paradox phrase. Because "several" explicitly means "multiple" and "default" implicitly means "unique".

Hope to receive some convincing explanations. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just states what you are saying: a developer cannot establish two different values by default for a template member function.